# How to use bash variable as awk input file

Tags: bash, awk

There is one line of awk in the middle of bash script throws error and I don't know how to fix.

Here is a simplified example:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=$(find -L . | grep file.txt.gz | awk '{printf "<(gunzip -c %s)", $1}' )
awk '{print $1}' ${filename}
```

When running this script, I got the following error messages:

```
++ find -L .
++ grep file.txt.gz
++ awk '{printf "<(gunzip -c %s)", $1}'
+ filename='<(gunzip -c ./file.txt.gz)'
+ awk '{print $1}' '<(gunzip' -c './file.txt.gz)'
awk: fatal: cannot open file `<(gunzip' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The problem comes from extra `'` inside bash variable `'<(gunzip' -c './file.txt.gz)'`, but I don't know where the `'` comes from?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `find -L . -name 'file.txt.gz' -exec gunzip -c {} + | awk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: @oguzismail Not exactly, I am trying to make awk take both txt and txt.gz file in one line. I didn't post the full script so it could be confusing.

Comment: Looks to me like the logic for execution isn't sound at all. @oguzismail approach seems a lot more logical

Answer (score 0):

From the awk man page:

> ```
>    -v var=val
>    --assign var=val
>          Assign the value val to the variable var, before execution  of  the
>          program  begins.
> ```

Hence, if you invoke your awk program by

```
awk -v P1="$1" '{printf "<(gunzip -c %s)", P1}'
```

you should get the desired effect.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In what respect?

Comment: @theronless : Here is a [proof of concept](https://ideone.com/NvIyO1) to demonstrate passing the parameter.

Comment: $1 inline should be output from grep, not a bash variable.

Comment: Maybe it wouls help if you described, what your script is supposed to do.